# Separating words in a string based on empty spaces with c#

Tags: c#, string

I have strings like this:

```
string mystring = "12353    90123B41094     A01283410294    3"
```

I need to separate this string that has 3 or 4 strings separated by empty spaces.

Here is my attempt:

```
   string block = "";
Arraytext = text.ToCharArray();
            for(int i = 0; i <= text.Length; i++)
            {
                while (Arraytext[i] !=' ') { block = block + Arraytext[i]; counter++; } // also tried Arraytext[i] != '/0'
            }
while (Arraytext [counter] == ' ')counter++; //to get where the next string begins
//repeat this function until the strings has been obtained
```

This doesn't work:

- The string block is filled with 0
- The Arraytext doesn't detect the empty spaces so the loop runs the entire string. I have tried `' '` and `'/0'`

Comment: Please make sure 'mystring' and 'text' are same in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To seperate the words between the spaces you can use

```
string mystring = "12353    90123B41094     A01283410294    3";
string[] result = mystring.Split(new []{' '},  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```